# Changing Linux I/O Scheduler Without Default Schedulers

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler

I'm working on a research on Linux kernel. I should add an I/O scheduler to Linux kernel. I compiled Linux 4.12.3 kernel. And this version has 3 default I/O scheduler (Noop - Deadline - Cfq). Now I can see the scheduler that I use and I can make changes between these three schedulers with these commands.

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
echo <sched.name> > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

But I couldn't use another scheduler that I have (.c, .o and mod.ko files) in the new kernel. (like Linus Elevator or BFQ). So I want to ask How can I add and then change my own I/O scheduler without compile the kernel.

And how can I see other non-default schedulers after this command?

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

Thanks..